# Deployment Issue with App on Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have deployed the app last November. During the review process, I followed all the steps for setting up a new app, and the Google Play Console production status indicates it's active. However, Google Play shows a URL not found, meaning the app is not deployed on the Google Play Store. I tried deploying the app in all testing modes, but it still doesn't appear on the Google Play Store in internal, closed testing, and all other modes. Only in production, internal testing, and closed testing, the status shows as active, but the application is not live. Please help me resolve this issue so that my app is live on the Google Play Store.

see this screen sort  https://prnt.sc/PcMW3JWq8B6i , https://prnt.sc/-mXPKh1bLra4